# Error starting ApplicationContext on running springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

The application builds but does not start. This was the default code from spring initializor that I cannot run.

Terminal Output :-

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2023-06-11T01:01:36.374+05:30 ERROR 24708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome.hashCode(ConditionOutcome.java:76)

The following method did not exist:

    'int org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.hashCode(boolean)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Ayushi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionOutcome.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Ayushi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.9/spring-core-6.0.9.jar!/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils: file:/C:/Users/Ayushi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.9/spring-core-6.0.9.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionOutcome and org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils
```

I have added a few dependencies on my own but I am not sure how that will effect this issue
POM.xml file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.CRUD</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-backend</name>
    <description>CRUD</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried multiple solutions online but I cannot figure this out. There is nothing specific mentioned to this particular error

Comment: why you are setting the version of `spring-boot-autoconfigure` to `1.2.1.RELEASE`? Have you tried to remove that line? If you check the [maven repo for spring-boot-autoconfigure](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure) you will see that the version was publish on **Jan 08, 2015**.

Comment: Hi Khare.  By adding the 1.2.1.RELEASE of the autoconfigure dependency, you've brought in a version that's incompatible.  Since you have the spring-boot-starter-parent as your parent, it defines the versions for you so if you exclude that version altogether, it should work for you.